# Handling Clicks From PaneFooter Items in NavigationView UWP

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I'm currently working on a UWP app and I have this `<NavigationView>` that handles `<NavigationViewItem>` clicks in the `<NavigationView.MenuItems>`. It seems not to recognise `<NavigationViewItem>` clicks in the `<NavigationView.PaneFooter>`.

This is the XAML code

```
<NavigationView x:Name="ControlNavigationView" Margin="0,0,0,0" IsSettingsVisible="False" Header="Welcome" SelectionChanged="NavigationView_SelectionChanged">
            <NavigationView.MenuItems>
                <NavigationViewItem Icon="OtherUser" Content="Positions" Tag="Positions"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Icon="People" Content="Workers" Tag="Workers"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Icon="Phone" Content="Customers" Tag="Customers"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Icon="Manage" Content="Materials" Tag="Materials"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Content="Flies" Tag="Flies">
                    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                        <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE24A;"/>
                    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                </NavigationViewItem>
                <NavigationViewItem Icon="Shop" Content="Orders" Tag="Orders"/>
                <NavigationViewItem Icon="Library" Content="Job Cards" Tag="Job Cards"/>
            </NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationView.PaneFooter>
                <NavigationViewItem Icon="Contact" Content="User" Tag="User"/>
            </NavigationView.PaneFooter>
            <Frame x:Name="ContentFrame">
                <Frame.ContentTransitions>
                    <TransitionCollection>
                        <NavigationThemeTransition/>
                    </TransitionCollection>
                </Frame.ContentTransitions>
            </Frame>
        </NavigationView>
```

The C# Code

```
private void NavigationView_SelectionChanged(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        switch (((NavigationViewItem)args.SelectedItem).Tag.ToString())
        {
            case "Positions":
                ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(UnderConstructionPage), ((NavigationViewItem)args.SelectedItem).Tag.ToString());
                ControlNavigationView.Header = ((NavigationViewItem)args.SelectedItem).Tag.ToString();
                break;
            case "Workers":
                ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(UnderConstructionPage), ((NavigationViewItem)args.SelectedItem).Tag.ToString());
                ControlNavigationView.Header = ((NavigationViewItem)args.SelectedItem).Tag.ToString();
                break;
            case "Customers":
                ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(UnderConstructionPage), ((NavigationViewItem)args.SelectedItem).Tag.ToString());
                ControlNavigationView.Header = ((NavigationViewItem)args.SelectedItem).Tag.ToString();
                break;
            case "Materials":
                ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(UnderConstructionPage), ((NavigationViewItem)args.SelectedItem).Tag.ToString());
                ControlNavigationView.Header = ((NavigationViewItem)args.SelectedItem).Tag.ToString();
                break;
            case "Flies":
                ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(UnderConstructionPage), ((NavigationViewItem)args.SelectedItem).Tag.ToString());
                ControlNavigationView.Header = ((NavigationViewItem)args.SelectedItem).Tag.ToString();
                break;
            case "Orders":
                ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(UnderConstructionPage), ((NavigationViewItem)args.SelectedItem).Tag.ToString());
                ControlNavigationView.Header = ((NavigationViewItem)args.SelectedItem).Tag.ToString();
                break;
            case "Job Cards":
                ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(UnderConstructionPage), ((NavigationViewItem)args.SelectedItem).Tag.ToString());
                ControlNavigationView.Header = ((NavigationViewItem)args.SelectedItem).Tag.ToString();
                break;
            case "User":
                ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(UnderConstructionPage), ((NavigationViewItem)args.SelectedItem).Tag.ToString());
                ControlNavigationView.Header = ((NavigationViewItem)args.SelectedItem).Tag.ToString();
                break;
        }
    }
```

How do i handle a click event on

```
<NavigationView.PaneFooter>
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Contact" Content="User" Tag="User"/>
</NavigationView.PaneFooter>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's by design. The `SelectionChanged` event will be fired only when the currently selected item changes in the menu.

In your case, you could register `Tap` event for this NavigationViewItem like the following:

```
<NavigationView.PaneFooter>
        <NavigationViewItem Icon="Contact" Content="User" Tag="User" Tapped="NavigationViewItem_Tapped"/>
</NavigationView.PaneFooter>
```

```
private void NavigationViewItem_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationViewItem navigationViewItem = sender as NavigationViewItem;
    ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(UnderConstructionPage), navigationViewItem.Tag);
    ControlNavigationView.Header = navigationViewItem.Tag;
}
```

Comment: Just try this solution out and found one issue, although the navigation would work, the indicator won't move to the new item. I have to move the selection to that item in code, and then found that I can't let the user select the one on the `MenuItems` that was selected before. The best use case would be just to navigate away from the current page entirely, or to display a content dialog on top of the current page.